# DICOM Send Error - Horos not sending files to Orthanc docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, orthanc-server

I am trying to send Patients scans to Orthanc server (docker based), getting an error while sending DICOM from Horos to Orthanc. using docker-compose to run my applications on Windows.

**note**: able to send files from Orthanc to Horos after adding DicomModaliteis to Orthanc configurations.

App details:

- Installed Horos v3 on MAc
- Installed docker based Orthanc on Windows 10 Home using Docker Toolbox, docker v19.x

Error:

```
DICOM StoreSCU operation failed.

DICOM Network Failure (STORE-SCU)
Association Request Failed 0006:031b Failed to establish association
0006:0317 Peer aborted Association (or never connected)
0006:031c TCP Initialization Error: Connection refused
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    orthanc:
        image: jodogne/orthanc-plugins:1.6.1
        container_name: orthancserver
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "4242:4242"
            - "8042:8042"
        networks:
            - mynetwork
        volumes:
            - /tmp/orthanc-db/:/var/lib/orthanc/db/
            - /c/Users/AppUser/Desktop/Project/orthanc.json:/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json:ro
networks:
    mynetwork:
        external: true
```

Comment: The output from Horus clearly says that the problem is on the underlying TCP/IP layer. So I would recommend to verify the TCP/IP connection with appropriate tools like ping and telnet.

Comment: @kritzel_sw, I am able to ping the IP address from Mac, also able to see the Orthanc dashboard on Mac's chrome browsers.

Comment: ...and you can reach the DICOM port configured for the Orthanc server in Horus (which is unfortunately missing in your question) via telnet?

Comment: @kritzel_sw, yes i have updated at Orthanc and found the solution, missing the port adding at VM Linux network 4242

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. Maybe you want to post your solution here so that we do not have a dangling question?

Comment: @kritzel_sw, Your comment helped me to trigger the solution, I have added the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Host IP not connected for the port 4242, Need to enter the port on Oracle VM's network, the Docker toolbox using the VM with Linux as default.

Steps to enable ports on VM:

1. Open Oracle VM
2. Right-click on default VM
3. Go to Settings and Select Network
4. Click on Advanced -> Port Forwarding
5. Click add icon and enter the ports
6. Enter 8042 and 4242 at both Host Port and Guest Port, leave other columns blank